# Pushfoward of measures Lipschitz continuous in total variation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be metric spaces and $f:X\times Y\to Z$ be a measurable map. Suppose that we are given a probability measure $\mu$ on $Y$, and define a stochastic kernel
$$
  \kappa(x,C):=\mu(\{y:f(x,y)\in C\}) = \mu(f_x^{-1}(C))
$$
for each $x\in X$ and measurable $C\subseteq Z$. I wonder when $\kappa$ is Lipschitz continuous in the total variation metric, that is how to find good bounds on $\sup_{C}|\kappa(x,C) - \kappa(x',C)|$ if we know the distance between $x$ and $x'$,
here the supremum is taken over all measurable subsets of $Z$.

One idea that I have is to use the fact that
$$
  |\kappa(x,C) - \kappa(x',C)| = \left|\mu\left(f_x^{-1}(C)\right) -  \mu\left(f_{x'}^{-1}(C)\right)\right|\leq\mu\left(f_x^{-1}(C)\Delta f_{x'}^{-1}(C)\right)
$$
where $\Delta$ denote the symmetric difference of sets. However, I think we need to require that $f$ has nice inverses: e.g. when $f(x,y)$ does not depend on $y$, then $\kappa(x)$ are Dirac measures, so obviously no Lipschitz continuity unless $f$ is also independent of $x$.